# CSS div extending beyond page limits, adds horizontal scrolling bar

Tags: html, css, width, scrollbar

I am currently working on a class project and I'm having issues where my div extends beyond the page limits for reasons unknown. This is what I mean:
[You can see that the div extends and adds a white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NLEf.png)

I am not entirely sure why this is; this is the code that I've written so far:

```css
    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
     background-image: url();
    }
    .logo{
     max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
     float:left;
    }
    .banner{
     width: 100%;
     height: 10%;
     background-color: #325999;
     }
    .bar_nav{
     background-color: rgb(66, 117, 201, 0.9);
     width: stretch;
     height: 30px;
     /*top y left son necesarios para que la barra se desplace*/
     left: 0px;
     top:0px;
     padding: 5px;
     z-index:100;
     position: sticky;
     margin: 0;
    }
    .boton_top{
     float: left;
     padding: 5px;
     margin-right: 5px;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 20px;
     font-family: verdana;
     vertical-align: middle;
     left: 0px;
     bottom: 2px;
     bottom: 18px;
     display: block;
     text-decoration: none;
     background-color: #84b3ff;
     color: white;
     position: relative;
     float:left;
    }
    .boton_top:after{
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 0;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
    }
    
    .boton_top:hover:after{
     width: 120%;
     background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
     transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    }
    .boton_top:hover{
     background-color: #0099ff;
    }
    
    .boton_banner{
     float: right; 
     padding: 5px;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 13px;
     font-family: verdana;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: white;
     background-color: #4e994e;
     /*border: 1px solid white;*/
     position:relative;
     display:block;
     margin: auto;
    }
    
    .boton_banner:hover{
     /*border: 3px solid white;*/
     font-size: 14px;
     background-color: #79bb79;
     transition: 0.2s;
    }
    
    .contenido{
     padding: 5px;
     background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
     margin-left: 10%;
     margin-right:10%;
     width:80%;
     position:relative;
     display:inline-block;
    }
```

```html
 <html>
    <head>
     <title> Eco Coelum </title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    
    <body >
    
    
    
    <div class="banner">
     <img src="img/logo.png" class="logo"/>
     <p><a href="regis.html" class="boton_banner">Registrate</a></p>
     <p><a href="login.html" class="boton_banner">Iniciar Sesión</a></p>
     <p><a href="asistencia.html" class="boton_banner">Asistencia</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="bar_nav">
     <p><a href="index.html" class="boton_top" >Home</a></p>
     <p><a href="productos.html" class="boton_top" >Productos</a></p>
     <p><a href="servicios.html" class="boton_top" >Servicios</a></p>
     <p><a class="boton_top" >Area Empleados</a></p>
    </div>
     <div class="contenido">
     <p>Texto</p>
     
     <p>BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABALBLABLA</p>
     <p>BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABALBLABLA</p>
     <p>BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABALBLABLA</p>
     <p>BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABALBLABLA</p>
     <p>BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABALBLABLA</p>
     </div>
    
    </body>
    
    
    </html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

add 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
     box-sizing: border-box;

to .contenido{}

you can read more about box-sizing here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Worked flawlessly. Thank you so much for the quick answer, I'll have a read over it when I have time! You're a lifesaver.